# Socket connection works over LAN but not WAN (internet)

Tags: java, sockets, port

I have a question which I'm sure is simple, but I don't know the answer.

I have created a chat program which allows two users to connect directly to each other provided they know the port and IP of the other user.

Socket

```
try {
        if (IP != null && checkIP(IP)) {
            connection = new Socket(IP, port);
            out = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    connection.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println("CONNECTED");

            printTimestamp();
            StyledDocument doc = mainText.getStyledDocument();
            Style style = mainText.addStyle("connection", null);
            StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.ORANGE);
            try {
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Connection open to:  " + IP + "\n", style);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ListenServer.stop();

            System.out.println("Making thread");
            runnable2 = new InputListener();
            thread2 = new Thread(runnable2);
            thread2.start();
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + IP);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: " + IP);
    }
```

ServerSocket

```
try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(ClientWindow.port);
        Settings.work = true;
        serverSocket.setSoTimeout(3000);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: " + ClientWindow.port);
        Settings.work = false;
    }

    while (running) {
        try {
            connection1 = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Accept failed port: " + ClientWindow.port);
        } catch(NullPointerException ne){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ClientWindow.window,
            "There was a fatal error in startup.\nPlease close ALL instances of Chattable before attempting to open the program again.",
            "Fatal Error",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            running = false;
        }

        try {
            if (connection1 != null) {
                out = new PrintWriter(connection1.getOutputStream(), true);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection1.getInputStream()));
                System.out.println("Accepted over server");
                runnable2 = new InputListener();
                thread2 = new Thread(runnable2);
                thread2.start();
                running = false;

                StyledDocument doc = mainText.getStyledDocument();
                Style style = mainText.addStyle("connection", null);
                StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.ORANGE);
                try {
                    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "[ " + getCurrentTimeStamp() + " ] Connection open to:  " + connection1.getRemoteSocketAddress() + "\n", style);
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O.");
        }
    }
```

This system works perfectly over LAN, however when you try and use it over the internet it throws an IOException from the Socket code. Is this using TCP or UDP? What does this mean for what I am trying to do. Does anyone have any tips about how to get this to work? Is it a matter of the port not being open?

Thanks!

Comment: An `IOException` will contain a detail message with more specific information about what went wrong.  Change `System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O");` and `System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: " + IP);` to `System.out.println(e);` and post the extra details.

Comment: Can you provide the `IOException` stacktrace ? As you said, the firewall can block it if you don't open the port. Moreover, I hope you don't use the private IP (`10.0.0.0/8`, `172.16.0.0/12` or `192.168.0.0/16`) the reach the server over internet.

Comment: Is it at your home or your work? If it's at home then you need to forward the appropriate port in your router, also the target machine's firewall should be notify of this incoming port. If it's at work then talk with the communications staff to let that port get into the intranet and forward to the specific local IP address. Also when accessing from the Internet you need to use, at the client, the public IP and not the private local IP. With your internet explorer connect to this [page](http://www.whatismyip.com) to find it out.

Comment: Yeah, I have been using public IP. The exception that occurred after waiting a bit was: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Is this using TCP or UDP?***

TCP

***What does this mean for what I am trying to do. Does anyone have any tips about how to get this to work?***

See below.

***Is it a matter of the port not being open?***

Most likely, but you should be able to get more detail from your `IOException` to confirm the cause.

In this question I have answered provided details on port forwarding that you may find useful; [C++ Sockets with Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084514/c-sockets-with-router/18088520#18088520)

You may also need to configure a firewall to allow ports external access depending on your environment.